# C# Call Constructor from Type while removen out of IList

Tags: c#

I have a List full of Observers

```
//create the list
Class ObersverList : IList<Observer>
```

the class Observer is having an dynamically Form which shows some infos. I want a clean way to kill the Form.

In the List i implemented something like

```
// preiodically call from programm to have always a nice updated list
observerlist.RemoveClosedHandles();

//observerlist.cs
public void RemoveClosedHandles() {
    _list.RemoveAll(ObserverActivePredicate);
}

private static bool ObserverActivePredicate(Oberver o) {
    return !o.HasHandle;
}
```

this caused that the ObserverList is pretty nice, and its working great, but i have to problems.
a) the observer is not killed, its just gone out of the list (no problem for me)
b) the form stays open.(thats a huge problem)

iwant something like using the constructor

```
//observer.cs
   activate() {
      HUD = new ObserverHud();
    }
    ~Observer(){
        HUD.Close();
        HUD.Dispose(); 
    }
```

but i dont know how to call the observerdestructor and kill the element, while removing.
is there an elegant c# way or do i need to jump through the list, find the to removing element and dispose it?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i did it now with IDisposable. solved